# image unlink in php

Tags: php

i added images in single id more than images but if delete that images in delete button. only one image delete that folder remaining images not delete that folder. how to delete that remaining images ??????

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from urbanesqe_completed_image WHERE id ='".$_GET['del']."'");
////echo "select * from urbanesqe_completed_image WHERE id ='".$_GET['del']."'";
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$product_image = $res['product_image'];
$image_path = "../images/completed/".$product_image;
unlink($image_path);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM urbanesqe_completed WHERE id ='".$_GET['del']."'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM urbanesqe_completed_image WHERE id ='".$_GET['del']."'");
```

Comment: *sigh* http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: As pointed out by Quentin, your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection. In other words, everyone can do anything they want with your database records. For example, (the good scenario) delete everything or (the bad scenario) steal everything (like passwords etc).

Comment: i added images in single id more than images but if delete that images in delete button. only one image delete that folder remaining images not delete that folder. how to delete that remaining images ??????

Comment: how to delete that remaining images ??????how?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one record in the `urbanesqe_completed_image` table then make a loop like

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $product_image = $res['product_image'];
  $image_path = "../images/completed/".$product_image;
  unlink($image_path);
}
```

so it will delete all the images

Answer (score -2):

You need to call `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop. There is an example in [the manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)